# Exception: The remote name could not be resolved: "url"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a desktop application which call asp.net mcv controller's action and get the response. Its working fine for most of the time but sometimes desktop application receive an exception "The remote name could not be resolved: url"

Here is the function in desktop application which makes http-post request:

```
> private bool postRequest(string uri, string json, out string jsonResult)
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 if (CheckForInternetConnection())
>                 {
>                     var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
>                     httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
>                     httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
>                     httpWebRequest.Timeout = 300000;
>                     //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
> SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
>                     using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
>                     {
>                         //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject();
>                         //string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
>                         //{
>                         //    Username = "myusername",
>                         //    Password = "pass"
>                         //});
>                         streamWriter.Write(json);
>                         streamWriter.Flush();
>                         streamWriter.Close();
>                     }
> 
>                     var res = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
>                     var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)res;
>                     //message = httpResponse.ToString();
>                     //jsonResult = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
>                     //message = httpResponse.StatusDescription;
>                     //return true;
>                     using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
>                     {
>                         var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
>                         jsonResult = result.ToString();
>                         return true;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     throw new Exception("Problem in internet connection.");
>                 }
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 //using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\Shubham\Desktop\log.txt"))
>                 //{
>                 //    Log(ex.Message, w);
>                 //}
>                 throw ex;
>             }
> 
>         }
```

below is one of Action in asp.net mcv which get called by desktop application:

```
> [HttpPost]
>         public ActionResult getSku(EmployeeDetails emp)
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 if (helper.getSku(emp, out SkuDetails skuDt))
>                 {
>                     JsonCreateResult json = new JsonCreateResult()
>                     {
>                         ex = null,
>                         id = skuDt.SemId,
>                         Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(skuDt),
>                         statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Found
>                     };
>                     return Json(json);
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     var key = dictionary.GetOrAdd(emp.SubscriberId+emp.EmployeeRole, new object());
>                     bool flag;
>                     SkuDetails skuDetails;
>                     lock (key)
>                     {
>                         flag = helper.getSkuFromSm(emp, out skuDetails);
>                     }
>                     if (flag)
>                     {
>                         JsonCreateResult json = new JsonCreateResult()
>                         {
>                             ex = null,
>                             id = skuDetails.SemId,
>                             Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(skuDetails),
>                             statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Found
>                         };
>                         return Json(json);
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                         JsonCreateResult json = new JsonCreateResult()
>                         {
>                             ex = null,
>                             id = string.Empty,
>                             Message = string.Empty,
>                             statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound
>                         };
>                         return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 helper.getErrorInBuild(emp.SubscriberId, "getSku", ex.Message, emp.EmployeeId + emp.EmployeeRole, string.Empty);
>                 JsonCreateResult json = new JsonCreateResult()
>                 {
>                     ex = ex,
>                     id = string.Empty,
>                     Message = string.Empty,
>                     statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
>                 };
>                 return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
>             }
>         }
```

I use lock() and static ConcurrentDictionary in asp.net mvc controller as you can see in above mentioned Action. I don't know if this is the reason for the problem as if static variable stored over data then limit. 
This desktop application is running on multiple desktops and each generate request in parallel.
Please help me if anyone know about this exception and solution for it

The exception I got [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmQPn.png)

Comment: If you use the wrong URL in a POST request you'd get an error. As for locks and ConcurrentDictionary, yes, locks aren't needed. *That* lock won't do anything at all though as it locks around a local variable.

Comment: If thats indeed the error, somewhere your url is "url" "http://..." if the name is unresolvable there are sometimes other reasons, such as companies with proxy servers your pc doesnt need to know how to lookup the server name, only the proxy server does

Comment: I guess you are missing http/https in your url string. Since you are trying to communicate with http protocol, you need to place that.

Comment: Problem is not with the http/htps as I already mentioned it in url. As I stated above desktop application working most of the time. If the problem is with http/https then it shouldn't worked at all

Comment: Is you web application running all the time? I mean if it is running on IIS Express then there are chances that the express server is sleeping if not being accessed for some time

Comment: Yes, it hosted on azure

Comment: Your application can never guarantee network connectivity. That's outside your code's control, hence your application should have a resilience strategy against network issues, maybe the network goes momentarily down, it happens. Try something like Polly (http://www.thepollyproject.org/) to implement periodic retries, or handle such exceptions. NB: `CheckForInternetConnection()` cannot be guaranteed as the network down can occur right after the check, but before your actual web request (it happens).

Comment: Its already implemented this internet connectivity check before postRequest function call.